# "Has a" relationship in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a package for all the model data. It contains game_cards, and user. Now I want another module called the_game which HAS those two modules. Rather than just make the_game the same level in the hierarchy. How would I do this? I have studied [this tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php) but it doesn't really give a code example of the Has-A relationship. Only the Is-A.

My package structure is:

```
model/user
     /game_cards
```

I would like:

```
model/the_game
              /user
              /game_cards
```

Comment: After more research, I think I just make the new module in model called the_game. Then I give it variables which are instances of my cards and the user.

Comment: @jwodder Python. I was just going to translate the language if I understood the concept. Thanks.

Comment: I frankly do not fully understand the problem. I think you are trying to apply Java patterns to Python - which makes things more complicated than necessary. Maybe you could elaborate more on the problem your trying to solve and why and how you would need a HAS for that

Comment: @schacki I'm just implementing a Has-A relationship. I think I have done it, as explained in my top comment. The game has cards and a user. I will answer it soon if no one disagrees.